# need to find the number of files in folders and sub folders except .dat files

Tags: python

I need to find the number of files in folders and sub folders except .dat files, here is my code:

```
import os

directoryPath = r'C:\Users\\vishns\Documents\Python_Code\Test_Folder'

number_of_files = sum(
    len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(directoryPath)
)

print(number_of_files)
```

Comment: See [How to filter a list](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-filter-list/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
import os

nfiles = 0
ndat = 0
directory = "C://Users//vishns//Documents//Python_Code//Test_Folder"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".dat"):
            ndat += 1
        else:
            nfiles += 1
        
print('Number of dat files:{}'.format(ndat))
print('Number of relevant files:{}'.format(nfiles))
print('Number of total files:{}'.format(ndat+nfiles))
```